# Azure AlertRule queries sometimes changes query

Tags: kql, azure-alerts

I have an Azure AlertRule what validates a query, where to tables are joining on a timestamp.
Is seems like Azure is changing the query, replacing the statement `bin(..)` with `bin_at(..)`.

The Original query:
[image: before]

The query, opened after the alert triggered.
[image: after]

In my case this change is enough to alter the result of the query, becuase the extra added parameter (yellow arrow).

Is there any way around the issue?

EDIT:

as David pointed out in the comments -
This behaviour can be reproduced by running this kql as the query of an alart rule:
`print bin(now(), 1h)`

Original:

For completness, i've added the entier query here. I was not able to shorten it more that this. (sorry)

```
let frame_size = 1h;
let messages = datatable (timestamp: datetime ) 
[
    datetime(2022-11-09T23:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T23:02:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T23:03:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T23:04:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T22:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T22:02:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T22:03:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T22:04:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T21:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T21:02:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T21:03:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T21:04:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T20:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T20:02:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T20:03:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T20:04:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T19:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T19:02:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T19:03:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T19:04:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T18:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T18:02:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T18:03:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T18:04:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T17:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T17:02:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T17:03:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T17:04:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T16:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T16:02:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T16:03:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T16:04:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T15:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T15:02:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T15:03:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T15:04:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T14:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T14:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T13:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T13:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T12:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T12:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T11:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T11:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T10:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T10:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T09:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T09:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T08:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T08:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T07:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T07:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T06:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T06:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T06:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T06:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T05:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T05:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T04:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T04:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T03:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T03:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T02:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T02:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T01:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T01:02:00Z),
    datetime(2022-11-09T00:01:00Z),datetime(2022-11-09T00:02:00Z),
]; 
let create_time_intervals = (start_datetime: datetime, end_datetime: datetime, frame_size: timespan) 
{
    let hourly_distribution_as_dk_time = datatable (hour: int, expected_documents_count: int)
    [0,2, 1,2, 2,2, 3,2, 4,2, 5,2, 6,2, 7,2, 8,2, 9,2, 10,2, 11,2, 12,2, 13,2, 14,2, 15,4, 16,4, 17,4, 18,4, 19,4, 20,4, 21,4, 22,4, 23,4 ]
    ; 
    let start_datetime_dk = datetime_utc_to_local(start_datetime, "Europe/Copenhagen");
    let end_datetime_dk = datetime_utc_to_local(end_datetime, "Europe/Copenhagen");
    // Generate all time frames for given interval excluding the first incomplete frame.
    range frame_start from bin(start_datetime + frame_size, frame_size) to end_datetime step frame_size 
    | project bin(frame_start, frame_size)
    | extend date_dk = datetime_utc_to_local(frame_start, "Europe/Copenhagen")
    | extend hour = toint(datetime_part("Hour", date_dk))
    | join kind=leftouter hourly_distribution_as_dk_time on hour
    | project frame_start, expected_documents_count
    | order by frame_start asc
};
let msg = messages
| where timestamp >= ago(1h)
|summarize cnt = count() 
    by frame_start = bin(timestamp,frame_size); // *** <==== this bin(..) changes when running ***
let frame_results = create_time_intervals(ago(1h), now(), frame_size)
| join kind=leftouter msg on frame_start
| extend ok = cnt;
frame_results
| summarize 
    sum_expected = sum(expected_documents_count),
    sum_ok = sum(ok)
| extend ok = sum_expected == sum_ok
| extend ok_int = toint(ok) //for alerting purposes
```

Comment: Azure is a big place. Please tag your question with the relevant service.

Comment: I would claim that a simple snippet such as the following, is more than enough to reproduce the issue. `print bin(now(), 1h)`

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz if I put our query into an AlertRule- the AlertRule will replace the `bin(..)` with `bin_at(..)` ? i'll give it a try :)

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz you are correct! it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, an obvious work-around would be to replace `bin` with `bin_at`, e.g. -

```
let timestamp = datetime(2000-03-04 11:22:33);
let frame_size = 1h;
print bin_at(timestamp, frame_size, datetime(2000))
```

| print_0 |
| --- |
| 2000-03-04T11:00:00Z |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEoycxNLS5JzC1QsFVISSxJBfE1jAwMDHQNjHUNTBQMDa2MjKyMjTWtuXKAytOKEnNT44szq1KB6g0zrLkKijLzShSSMvPiE0s04IbpICnUQTVXUxMASzoP9HcAAAA=)

Comment: hmm, that a good idea - replace it before azure does :) I'll give a try.

Comment: For the senario I posted - your solution does work, because the 3. th param in `bin_at(..)` needs to be a constant. In my real senario, I don't have constant values (the timestamp keeps moving).

Comment: You seem to have some insight into why Azure is doing this - can you point me to some documentation ? :)

Comment: The 1st parameter is your timestamp. The 3rd parameter is just a fixed point in time you bin your timestamp according to. There is no reason for it not to be a constant.

Comment: As to "Azure" behavior (once again, Azure is a big place), please post a new question with a detailed description of the entire flow.